# WFS GetFeature request failing with srsName

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I have a WFS 2.0 GetFeature request that works when I query a point layer but when I use essentially the same request on a line layer it throws the following error:

> Error: JSON does not allow non-finite numbers

The problem seems to be with the `srsName` option. If I remove the `srsName` option, the polyline will return the JSON correctly. The points layer request works correctly with or without the `srsName` option.

The features are stored in PostGIS database as a Multilinestring. The SRS I am trying to reproject to (4326) is included in the '**Extra SRS codes for WFS capabilities generation**' option in GeoServer's WFS settings.

Doesn't work with `JSONP (or JSON) and srsName`:

```
http://<path>:8080/geoserver/Ramnode/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Ramnode%3Asimplifysurveyedsp&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript&format_options=callback%3AgetJson&count=3&srsName=EPSG%3A3857&callback=getJson&_=1478180151772
```

Works as `GML2 with srsName` (example 1) and as `JSONP without srsName` (example2):

```
http://<path>:8080/geoserver/Ramnode/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Ramnode%3Asimplifysurveyedsp&outputFormat=GML2&format_options=callback%3AgetJson&count=3&srsName=EPSG%3A3857

http://<path>:8080/geoserver/Ramnode/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Ramnode%3Asimplifysurveyedsp&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript&format_options=callback%3AgetJson&count=3&callback=getJson&_=1478180151772
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this would work for points but not work on polylines?

```
2016-11-03 12:36:49,208 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/Ramnode/ows]
2016-11-03 12:36:49,209 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/Ramnode/ows]
2016-11-03 12:36:49,209 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/Ramnode/ows] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@6a432a5b] and 1 interceptor
2016-11-03 12:36:49,210 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find kvp parser for: 'callback'. Storing as raw string.
2016-11-03 12:36:49,211 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wfs.WFSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[Ramnode], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS]]
2016-11-03 12:36:49,211 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2016-11-03 12:36:49,211 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wfs.WFSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[Ramnode], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS]]
2016-11-03 12:36:49,212 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wfs.WFSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[Ramnode], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS]]
2016-11-03 12:36:49,213 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - Query is org.geoserver.wfs.request.Query$WFS20@66dfbc2f
 To gt2: Query:
   feature type: simplifysurveyedsp
   filter: Filter.INCLUDE
   [properties:  ALL ]
2016-11-03 12:36:49,217 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 2.0
    baseUrl = http://<path>:8080/geoserver/
    count = 3
    outputFormat = text/javascript
    resolve = none
    resolveDepth = *
    resolveTimeout = 300
    resultType = results
    formatOptions = {CALLBACK=getJson}
    abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.QueryTypeImpl@5f91f2dd (handle: null) (abstractProjectionClause: null, abstractSelectionClause: null, abstractSortingClause: null, aliases: null, typeNames: [{ramnode}simplifysurveyedsp]) (featureVersion: null, srsName: EPSG:3857, filter: null, propertyNames: null, sortBy: null)
    abstractQueryExpression[0]:
        typeNames[0] = {ramnode}simplifysurveyedsp
        srsName = EPSG:3857
2016-11-03 12:36:49,218 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2016-11-03 12:36:49,218 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wfs.WFSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[Ramnode], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS]]
2016-11-03 12:36:49,219 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error: JSON does not allow non-finite numbers
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.write(GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.java:322)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:191)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:990)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: JSON does not allow non-finite numbers
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONUtils.testValidity(JSONUtils.java:586)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONUtils.numberToString(JSONUtils.java:453)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONUtils.valueToString(JSONUtils.java:657)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONBuilder.value(JSONBuilder.java:344)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.value(GeoJSONBuilder.java:301)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.value(GeoJSONBuilder.java:41)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONBuilder.value(JSONBuilder.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.writeCoordinate(GeoJSONBuilder.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.writeCoordinates(GeoJSONBuilder.java:146)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONBuilder.writeGeom(GeoJSONBuilder.java:89)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.write(GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.java:223)
    ... 93 more
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace from the logs?

Comment: Having the URL for the WFS requests (both a failing one and a good one) would also be helpful to understand the problem

Comment: if you request GML and not JSON do you also get an error?

Comment: The GML request does not fail. I am working with him on this. I'll get the logs Andrea.

Comment: @AndreaAime I have added the log results when set to developer logging. And I have added three example requests with the url replaced by <path>

Comment: Have you tried converting the GML output to GeoJSON away from the geoserver? The error indicates a whole host of possible problems. I've run a quick test on a system of mine and the only way I can reproduce it is if I place a line into the polar regions (i.e. a region EPSG:3857 doesn't cover). But that behaviour is identical with points.

Comment: Another option to investigate is whether any IDs of the lines could be mistaken for infinite numbers (e.g. 10e56789). Though this should be causing errors regardless of the srsName if it had an effect.

Comment: @PhilG To your first comment - you are suggesting taking the GML output, running it through ogr2ogr and converting to GeoJSON? I will do that and will update afterwards.

Comment: @DonF yes, either that or running it through any parser that converts between the two. If it converts fine and can be validated it would narrow down the underlying issues.

Comment: On a different note you say you want to reproject to EPSG:4326, but your stack trace and url indicate you're requesting srsName=EPSG:3857.

Comment: @PhilG Yeah, we tried it with both projections.

Comment: The version number you give in all your request examples is not valid, it should be `version=2.0.0&` not `version=2.0&`

Comment: Maybe because of the WFS version? you must use crs instead of srs? https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/basics.html

Comment: `you must use crs instead of srs?` you're thinking of WMS versions, not WFS